# Typescript require param if another param is passed, multiple times

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do a distributed union type where the passing of one key, makes other keys required.

```js
interface BaseArgs {
    title: string
}

interface FuncPagerArgs {
    enablePager: true
    limit: number
    count: number
}

type FuncArgs = (FuncPagerArgs & BaseArgs) | BaseArgs;

function func(args: FuncArgs) {
    if ("enablePager" in args) {
        pager({ limit: args.limit, count: args.count });
    }
}

interface PagerArgs {
    limit: number
    count: number
}

function pager(args: PagerArgs) {

}

func({
    title: "something",
    enablePager: true
})
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QIJQOYbIDeAUMucmMGADYQBcyGYUoeJAviSaJLIigBiAVxAIACnDzRcBYmQoQQcAEZ1J0qIxbCIC8jWABbaoxDCjK6PuQIA9qLBmLVqJ25gAngAchohLKEALzIABQiYhoy+IQAZGiYODEAlMgAPglYgQDc3DD+VHYgyPlioXAxjBEBKfIUyMAwYQBESqrqUtDNDcUVBKmk9fXenVChRMiGJk7IfRgAdFPUADS2DuCMc-P2jsgcybn1XFw84NDwSMhRUIF1FEsz5pbW9TsbyE+u7iSlCIXFI005UqV1GgQG3BOv3GNiotAYyGaGDsRggYAAFmxmssbG01BBrtooLpOMkgA

To me, that code should not pass validation because I'm calling `func` while passing enablePager, but I did not pass `limit` or `count` when both are required when `enablePager` is true. In my real world example, I was trying to do this pattern for 3 or 4 different feature booleans, each which will alter the contract to require some more fields. Unfortunately I can't even the first feature boolean to work, let alone multiple.

Answer (score 0):

The issue we are seeing here is related to not having proper discriminant between elements of the union. We have overlap between two members  `(FuncPagerArgs & BaseArgs) | BaseArgs`, the overlap is equal `BaseArgs`. What is very important is also [behavior of function argument types in TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance):

> When comparing the types of function parameters, assignment succeeds if either the source parameter is assignable to the target parameter, or vice versa.

What does it mean - if our type is assignable to the wanted type, or wanted type is assignable to our argument type you can pass it. Consider the test:

```
type ArgType = {
    title: "something",
    enablePager: true
}
type IsAssignable = ArgType extends FuncArgs ? true : false; // true, can be passed
```

So type you are passing is assignable to the wanted type, then TS allows it to be passed. Not ask me why, this is design decisions, and you can understand it as a compromise, being more strict would block many wanted behaviors, at least that is stated in the TS docs I have linked above. For sure there is now the issue inside the code which will make us the runtime error.

In order to fix it we need to create proper discriminated union without overlap.

```
interface BaseArgs {
    title: string
}

interface OnlyTitle extends BaseArgs {
    kind: 'TITLE'
}

interface FuncPagerArgs extends BaseArgs {
    kind: 'PAGER'
    enablePager: true
    limit: number
    count: number
}

type FuncArgs = OnlyTitle | FuncPagerArgs;

function func(args: FuncArgs) {
    if (args.kind === 'PAGER') {
        pager({ limit: args.limit, count: args.count });
    }
}

interface PagerArgs {
    limit: number
    count: number
}

function pager(args: PagerArgs) {

}

func({
    kind: "TITLE",
    enablePager: true
}) // error 

func({
    kind: "TITLE",
    title: 'title'
}) // correct
```

What I did is [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) in form of `kind` property which will allow on proper members without any overlap. It means now you can only use or one or another variant, the type never overlap.

### Edit after the comment

In the comment author has stated he needs to combine all options togethere, but when something is enabled all options related to that should go within. Such kind of structure we can do by separation of options in groups + joining them. Consider:

```
interface Base {
    title: string
}
interface Pager  {
  pager?: {
    limit: number
    count: number
  }  
}

interface Sort {
  sorter?: {
    columns: string[] // example property
  }  
}

type Options = Pager & Sort & Base;

function func(args: Options) {
    if (args.pager) {
        pager({ limit: args.pager.limit, count: args.pager.count });
    }
    if (args.sorter) {
       sorter(args.sorter.columns)
    }
}

func({
  title: 'title',
  pager: {count: 2, limit: 10} // all fields its ok
})


func({
  title: 'title',
  pager: {count: 2} // error limit is missing
})
```

Now we can have `pager` and `sorter` together, when you have `pager` you need to put all options related to it as they are required.

Comment: That type of discriminated union totally prevents the ability to do multiple at once. The issue I have is I want to have multiple feature toggles, and each will have their own required properties. If I have to have a string literal as the discriminant, then I cannot have multiple. Is there no way to use an array or object as the discriminant? `features : { pager : true }` or `features : ["pager"]` that way another arg object could be `features : ["pager", "sorting"]` etc?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I updated my answer, I think this is what you need.